# How to detect a change in any <td> of table, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a Table whose `<td>` values varies depending upon the inputs given in form, I am using [Tangle](http://worrydream.com/Tangle/guide.html) to make a reactive document. Is it posible to detect if the value of `<td>`changes to any negative number? If so, then it must change its color to red!
Can Javascripting or html tags itself solve this problem?
Please help!
My change will be on profitLossIn1,profitLossIn2,profitLossIn3.
Here is my html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Revenue</th>
        <th>Result Profit/Loss</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id='NameInn1' type='text' NAME="NameInn1"></td>
        <td><span class="TKNumberField" data-var="CostIn1"></span></td>
        <td><b data-var="revenueIn1"> Cost</b></td>
        <td><b data-var="profitLossIn1"> dollars</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id='NameInn2' type='text' NAME="NameInn2"></td>
        <td><span class="TKNumberField" data-var="CostIn2"></span></td>
        <td><b data-var="revenueIn2"> Cost</b></td>
        <td><b data-var="profitLossIn2"> dollars</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id='NameInn3' type='text' NAME="NameInn3"></td>
        <td><span class="TKNumberField" data-var="CostIn3"></span></td>
        <td><b data-var="revenueIn3"> Cost</b></td>
        <td><b data-var="profitLossIn3"> dollars</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><b data-var="totalRevenueIn"> dollars</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("profitLossOut1");
console.log(inputs.value);
inputs.onchange = function () {
    console.log("Checking IF condition");
    if ((parseInt(this.value)).match("-") == true) this.parentNode.style.background = "red";
};
```

Comment: 1. Get all the td's in your document
2. Loop through them and get text of td
3. Check if "-" is found in text 
4. Change color (.css)

Comment: put your javascript here too. especially the `update: function() {}`

Comment: @niels123 that's not going to be dynamic though. I don't know tangle but it seems like you would want it dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you don't want to check for negative values of the **inputs**, you want to check for negative values of the tangle-generated **text** values.

This code should be more of what you're looking for, and it works as long as the text content of your `data-var` elements starts with the number. If not, the number parsing logic will need to be improved:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").change(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        var checkNeg = function(c) {
            for(var i=0,$ci; i<c.length; i++) {
                $ci = $(c[i]);
                if(parseInt($ci.text()) < 0) $ci.css("color", "red");
                else $ci.css("color", "black");
            }
        };
        checkNeg($target.parents("table").find("[data-var]"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe this can be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/tz7WB/

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$(":input").on("change", function () {
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) < 0) $(this).closest("td").css("background", "red");
})
```

try to type any negative number in the inputs

---

with pure js: http://jsfiddle.net/tz7WB/1/

**JS CODE**

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    inputs[x].onchange = function () {
        if (parseInt(this.value) < 0) this.parentNode.style.background = "red";
    };
}
```

Comment: What about `-0`? (I know, I *know*)

Comment: What if I try to check the values on every change in cell? I am trying someting like this from your code:

Comment: uhm you forgot to paste the link? :D

Comment: if you refer to your question update: you are trying to match a "-" on an Int. You should instead remove the parseInt function, and match the minus on the string input value, as this:http://jsfiddle.net/WZ4sr/

Comment: I have tried this now:
var loss = document.getElementById("profitLossOut1").value;
        console.log(loss);
        loss.onchange = function () {
            console.log("Checking IF condition");
            if (loss.match("-") == true) this.parentNode.style.background = "red";
        };

Answer (score 0):

Consider using knockout.js for your scenario, you can use it to easily format your UI elements according to the underlying data. Take a look at the examples: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery change events for each of input boxes . Below is sample code

```
$("#NameInn1").change(function(){
   var input = $("#NameInn1").val();
   if(input<10){
     $("#NameInn1").css("background-color","red");
   }
});
```